# Disputing a charge on the credit card if the item arrives much later than expected

Tags: united-states, credit-card

I purchased an item from a website not very long ago. For whatever amount I paid for shipping it said delivery estimated between Day T and Day T+5. Say I received the item on Day T+12. This item was important to my well being and I clearly feel dissatisfied that it arrived so late. If I called the vendor and told them they would probably say they don't care. However I used my credit card to pay for this so my question is the following:

Is there grounds in disputing this charge on the CC under

"I ordered merchandise or service from this merchant but the merchant was unable to provide the merchandise or service I ordered."

What would the likely outcome be if I did this dispute? Ideally I would want to keep the item and get some sort of refund.

Answer (score 1):

The dispute would almost certainly be denied on the basis that you have kept the item.

If you want a refund, return the item.  If you return the item and the vendor doesn't issue the proper refund, dispute the charge.  You can't keep the item and get a refund and most (I think it's all, but I'll say most because there may be an outlier) credit card issuers can only cancel entire transactions, not 70% or whatever of a transaction.

Comment: The credit card company would cancel the entire transaction even if you were only entitled to a partial refund. It would then be your responsibility to pay the merchant whatever you owed them. When a credit card company reverses a payment, all they're really doing is disintermediating themselves. Essentially, they're saying that they won't collect for the merchant because the merchant didn't perform as promised.

Comment: At the network level Visa and MC both support partial chargebacks, and I think most issuers support them too. I've done a few personally.

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally I would want to keep the item and get some sort of refund.

It doesn't work this way. Although a pizza chain might offer such a thing, 30 minutes or it's free, but other sellers of stuff typically don't agree to this.

Even with Amazon, "guaranteed by x date." So it comes a day late. As a prime member, I didn't pay extra for shipping. Why waste my time to say it's a day late, as I won't likely get anything back? Either way, you are right to be unhappy, but the best you might get is a refund of shipped fees, if any. In the end, money talks, you should express your unhappiness by buying elsewhere.

Comment: FYI, If you are a Prime subscriber and your package arrives late, you can get [a free month of Prime membership](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201117450). I've done this a couple of times.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, I didn't know this. $8 for a quick email or call is nothing to walk away from.